# Machine Learning in Python is way off and has over 50 loss

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

I have this code:

```py
import json
import numpy as np
print("This is a basic machine learning thing.")
baseData = {"collecting":True,"x":[],"y":[]}
while baseData["collecting"]:
  baseData["x"].append(int(input("X:")))
  baseData["y"].append(int(input("Y:")))
  if input("Do you want to keep feeding data? Press enter for yes, or type anything for no.") != "":
    baseData["collecting"] = False
if len(baseData["x"]) == len(baseData["y"]):
  xdata = baseData["x"]
  ydata = baseData["y"]
  nums = []
  for i in range(len(xdata)):
    nums.append(xdata[i] - ydata[i])
  median = np.median(nums)
else:
  print("malformed data")
def getY(x):
  pass
while True:
  data = input("X/Data:")
  print(float(data)+median)
```

My goal is to find the difference between each X and Y, and then find the median with those numbers (the average difference), then add them. While I don't get any errors, I have a lot of loss.

```
This is a basic machine learning thing.
X:10
Y:50
Do you want to keep feeding data? Press enter for yes, or type anything for no.no
X/Data:10
-30.0
```

This returned `-30.0` even though it should have returned `50` as I taught it that 10 should return 50. Any solutions?
If you want to fork this or try it out yourself you can use [my repl](https://repl.it/@UCYT5040/Machine-Learning-Graph#main.py).

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for getting help with code, not really for getting help with broad design questions or math or other stuff like that. See the [tour], the [ask] page, and this [help/on-topic] page for more info on what this site is about. And you yourself said this is more of a math question, so it might be more suitable for something like https://mathoverflow.net/ or https://datascience.stackexchange.com/, as long as you make sure to look at the rules for those sites before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to subtract instead of add at `print(float(data)+median)`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by ***"middle line"*** I'm not sure. However if what you want is the ***median*** (the center value relative to the size of the X & Y arrays), you could simply take the length of X & Y, divide it by half (make sure to round) and then get that value from your values.

Otherwise, I'm not sure what you mean, or how you're implementing machine learning in this.

Sounds like what you might be looking for is some form of interpolation of Y based on a few known values. Machine learning could do something like that, but you'd have to use some form of clustering, neural nets, random forests, or linear regression (etc.) with enough training and validation data.

I'd recommend looking into interpolation and linear regression. This might help you find a bearing of what you need to better ask your question.

Best of luck.